# Distro to install on a PowerPC G4 after Debian dropped 32-bit PPC support

Tags: distribution-choice, powerpc

Debian dropped support for my PowerPC CPU.

For this reason my security updates are now no longer granted and I am clearly not happy about that.

Is there any distro out there that supports PowerPC and provides an automatic compilation of updates on my PC?

In my hopes I can get a distro that in the moment I run something like `apt upgrade` downloads the packages from source, compiles locally and install.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Have you checked Distrowatch? https://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=All&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=powerpc&package=All&rolling=All&isosize=All&netinstall=All&language=All&defaultinit=All&status=Active#simple

Comment: Does it have to be Linux?

Comment: I would prefer Linux because I am used to it but I am also opened to other alternatives

Comment: Yes I checked distro watch and Google and I was not convinced. This is why I came to search for experts / powerpc users.

Comment: The [powerpc wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC#Operating_systems_2) seems to list most popular distributions as being supported.

Comment: @Jesse_b the wiki lists most popular distributions, but it also mentions when they dropped support for 32-bit PowerPC; AFAICT, the only distribution which still supports the G4 is Gentoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the impression the only “big” distribution with current support for 32-bit PowerPC is [Gentoo](https://www.gentoo.org/downloads/). This is a source-based distribution, which matches your criteria.

You can still get Debian packages from [the `powerpc` port](https://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/), but it’s no longer a released distribution — which effectively means you need to track testing or unstable.

Answer (score -2):

[openSUSE](https://opensuse.org/)

have been using this distro for a long time now

Coolest things about openSUSE are yast(a linux GUI config manager), great package manager and ...

Comment: Are you sure? The last version to support the G4 was 11.1, released over ten years ago.